# Azure release pipeline get build number of build pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a release pipeline for an asp.net 6 app which publishes the site to an IIS server. This release pipeline uses the artifacts published from the build pipeline. I link build pipeline to the release one

```
resources:
 pipelines:
     - pipeline: 'buildPipeline'
       project: 'My Asp Net App'
       source: 'Build pipeline'
       branch: 'main'
```

What Im trying to achieve is to get the version of the build pipeline into the release pipeline. I used the following powershell task to check the version

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Version output
  inputs:
    targetType: "inline"
    script: |                     
     Write-Error "Build version is $(Build.BuildNumber)"
```

and is outputting the version of the release pipeline instead of the build. How can I get it without using any external sources.

Comment: May I ask you what do you mean by  `linking build pipeline to release pipeline` using snippet you posted, if release pipeline doesn't support yml definition, but  only  UI ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the Build version of the Pipeline resource, you can use the variable: `resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runName`.

The variable: `resources.pipeline.<Alias>.runName` will pass the variable: `$(Build.BuildNumber)`  of build pipeline to release pipeline via pipeline resources.

For example:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Version output
  inputs:
    targetType: "inline"
    script: |                     
     Write-Error "Build version is $(resources.pipeline.buildPipeline.runName)"
```

Refer to this doc: [Pipeline resource variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pipeline-resource-variables)